# How to select certain paths based on their length to a node

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph, r-sf

I read this excellent post about sf and tidygraph, https://www.r-spatial.org//r/2019/09/26/spatial-networks.html

They created a graph object with the sf_to_tidygraph function described in the post.
Here is a simple reproducible example

```
nodes <- tibble("NodeID" = 1:4)
edges <- tibble("from" = c(1, 1,2,3,2), "to" = c(2, 3,3,4,4), "edgeID" = 1:5, 
            "length" = c(100, 200, 100, 200, 50))
graph <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges, directed = FALSE)
```

**I would like to select all paths based on their length to a specific node** and not only shortest paths. For shortest paths I have the following code:

```
distances <- distances(
    graph = graph,
    weights = graph %>% activate(edges) %>% pull(length)
    )

 table_distance <- 
      distances %>% 
      as_tibble() %>% 
      rownames_to_column("from") %>% 
      pivot_longer(2:5, names_to = "to", values_to = "distance") %>% 
      mutate(to = substring(to, 2))

 nodes_inf_300_to_node_1 <- table_distance %>% 
     filter(from == "1") %>% 
     filter(distance <= 300)  %>% 
     pull(to)

 path <- shortest_paths(graph, from = 1,
                   to = nodes_inf_300_to_node_1,
                   output = 'both',
                   weights = graph %>% 
                     activate(edges) %>% 
                     pull(length))
```

the "path" object gives me all shortest path from node 1 to the nodes which are inferior to a distance of 300.

But not all paths from node 1 to a distance max of 300 m. 
Is there an igraph function I am missing, or another solution ?

I could do :

```
 all_simple_paths(graph, 1, nodes_inf_300_to_node_1)
```

and then calculate the lenth of each path

But the function all_simple_path is too long for complex graph

all_simple_paths with a cutoff argument (max) and a weight argument

https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/774